# Select rows together with their previous rows given a condition for a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a DataFrame, where the "time" attribute is a Python timedelta object. The index attribute is internal to the pandas dataframe, I simply show it to make it easier to understand the problem.

| index | ID | time | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | NaT | ITL |
| 1 | 0 | 0 days 01:00:00 | USA |
| 2 | 0 | NaT | ITL |
| 3 | 0 | NaT | ESP |
| 4 | 0 | 2 days 00:05:00 | USA |
| 5 | 1 | NaT | ITL |
| 6 | 1 | 0 days 03:35:00 | USA |
| 7 | 1 | NaT | ESP |
| 8 | 2 | NaT | USA |
| 9 | 3 | NaT | FRA |
| 10 | 3 | 2 days 04:14:10 | ESP |
| 11 | 3 | 1 days 03:35:00 | ITL |

I divide the functionality in 2 steps:

1. Select the rows whose value of the attribute "time" is different from NaT.

| index | ID | time | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 days 01:00:00 | USA |
| 4 | 0 | 2 days 00:05:00 | USA |
| 6 | 1 | 0 days 03:35:00 | USA |
| 10 | 3 | 2 days 04:14:10 | ESP |
| 11 | 3 | 1 days 03:35:00 | ITL |

2. Select for each row of the above subset, its previous index row as long as it belongs to the same ID.

| index | ID | time | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | NaT | ITL |
| 1 | 0 | 0 days 01:00:00 | USA |
| 3 | 0 | NaT | ESP |
| 4 | 0 | 2 days 00:05:00 | USA |
| 5 | 1 | NaT | ITL |
| 6 | 1 | 0 days 03:35:00 | USA |
| 9 | 3 | NaT | FRA |
| 10 | 3 | 2 days 04:14:10 | ESP |
| 11 | 3 | 1 days 03:35:00 | ITL |

The DataFrame I want is the one above (without the index column, which is internal to pandas). I have split the functionality into 2 steps to make the problem understandable, however I need to get to step 2, it is not necessary that the functionality of step 1 comes implicit.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chain masks for testing non missing values with shifted values per groups by [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) with `|` for bitwise `OR` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = df['time'].notna()
df = df[m | m.groupby(df['ID']).shift(-1,fill_value=False)]
print (df)
    ID            time country
0    0             NaT     ITL
1    0 0 days 01:00:00     USA
3    0             NaT     ESP
4    0 2 days 00:05:00     USA
5    1             NaT     ITL
6    1 0 days 03:35:00     USA
9    3             NaT     FRA
10   3 2 days 04:14:10     ESP
11   3 1 days 03:35:00     ITL
```